# Do I need a webserver for a JSON database?

Tags: json, webserver, virtual-machine, dart

I am programming a database with Dart and JSON. So my question is:
When I want to run my app, do I have to have a real webserver running on my PC? And if yes, what kind of a program would you recommend and should it be packed in a virtual-machine?
Thanks in advance!
Karl

Comment: it looks like a lot of ppl hate dart server-side questions...

Comment: Sorry, this question is really vague. Stack Overflow is great for specific HOWTO type questions, with very clear answers. If you can rephrase to be very specific (like, include an error message) we can better help.

Answer (score 1):

Dart VM can run on the command line and it has a built-in web server. You can run Dart VM on Linux, Mac, and Windows. I can't really answer further unless you provide more specifics.

Comment: Could you maybe provide a link to a tutorial or an article that shows how one should "deploy" the server-side dart code on a server machine?

Comment: The best way to do it right now is Heroku. http://blog.sethladd.com/2012/08/running-dart-in-cloud-with-heroku.html